# Firefox: open a file without saving

Tags: firefox, download

It seems like after a recent update, when opening files with Firefox the files are also saved to a default download location, which isn't always desirable. How can files now be opened/viewed without saving them to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `about:config` set the `browser.download.improvements_to_download_panel` flag to false.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not seem to work.

To restore the former behaviour of saving opened/viewed files in a temporary folder, write `about:config` in the address bar and change `browser.download.start_downloads_in_tmp_dir` to `true`.